# redux forms are not working correctly here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I created a short Model included a form in it but the values that are going to handleSignup are undefined when accessed that really not suppose to happen I was expecting the JSON of the form submit there which is not working here. it's getting frustrating a little.

I have used Form from reactstrap and everything is working fine with it. but the Form component from react-redux-form is not working as expected

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {

  }
 }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 postUser: (user) => dispatch(postUser(user)),
 resetForm: () => {dispatch(actions.reset('form'))},
})

    class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isNavOpen: false,
      isModalOpen: false,
      isModalOpen2: false
    };

    this.toggleNav = this.toggleNav.bind(this);
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    this.toggleModal2 = this.toggleModal2.bind(this);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.handleSignup = this.handleSignup.bind(this);
  }


handleSignup (values) {
    const user = {
      firstname : values.fname,
      lastname : values.lname,
      email  : values.email,
      password : values.password,
      username : values.username
    }
    // {console.log('check hererre')}
    // {console.log(user)}
    this.toggleModal2();
    this.props.resetForm();
    this.props.postUser(user);
  }
.
.
.
.
.
```

This is now my modal

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen2} toggle={this.toggleModal2}>
    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal2} >Sign Up</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <div className="">
        <Form model="form" onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSignup(values)}>
          <FormGroup className="row">
            <Label htmlFor="username" md={4} >Username</Label>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <Control.text model=".username" id="username" name="username"
                placeholder="Username"
                className="from-control"
                validators={{required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(15)}}
                 />
               <Errors
                 className="text-danger"
                 model=".username"
                 show="touched"
                 messages={{
                   required : 'Required',
                   minLength : 'Must be greater than 2 charecters',
                   maxLength : 'Must be less than 15 charecters'
                 }}
                 />
             </div>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="row" >
            <Label htmlFor="fname" md={4}>First Name</Label>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <Control.text model=".fname" id="fname" name="fname"
                placeholder = "First Name"
                className="form-control"
                validators={{required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(15)}}
                 />
              <Errors
                className="text-danger"
                model=".fname"
                show="touched"
                messages={{
                  required : 'Required',
                  minLength : 'Must be greater than 2 charecters',
                  maxLength : 'Must be less than 15 charecters'
                }}
                />
            </div>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="row" >
            <Label htmlFor="lname" md={4} >Last Name</Label>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <Control.text model=".lname" id="lname" name="lname"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                className="form-control"
                validators={{required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(15)}}
                 />
               <Errors
                 className="text-danger"
                 model=".lname"
                 show="touched"
                 messages={{
                   required : 'Required',
                   minLength : 'Must be greater than 2 charecters',
                   maxLength : 'Must be less than 15 charecters'
                 }}
                 />
             </div>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="row" >
            <Label htmlFor="password" md={4}>Password</Label>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <Control.text type="password" model=".password" id="password" name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                className="form-control"
                validators={{required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(15)}}
                />
              <Errors
                className="text-danger"
                model=".password"
                show="touched"
                messages={{
                  required : 'Required',
                  minLength : 'Must be greater than 2 charecters',
                  maxLength : 'Must be less than 15 charecters'
                }}
                />
            </div>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="row" >
            <Label htmlFor="email" md={4}>Email</Label>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <Control.text type="email" model=".email" id="email" name="email"
                placeholder="E-Mail"
                className="form-control"
                validators={{required, validEmail}}
                />
              <Errors
                className="text-danger"
                model=".email"
                show="touched"
                messages={{
                  required : 'Required',
                  validEmail : 'invalid email address'
                }}
                />
            </div>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Button type="submit" color="primary" >SignUP NOW !</Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </ModalBody>
  </Modal>
```

And in end

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) 
(Header));
```

The expected result would be the values in handleSignup containg a JSON in it not values being undefined.

Comment: always it is easy to identify the issue ,when you break down the problem into chunks.

Comment: I am really beat on this one right now,,,,,the code is really supposed to work...

Comment: the onSubmit part on the form should reaaalllyyyy work....

Comment: What happens if you change `onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSignup(values)}` to `onSubmit={this.handleSignup}` ?

Comment: We need to pass onSubmit prop to the form component, but read handleSubmit inside of it. handleSubmit magically wrap onSubmit by reduxForm HOC. You can find more information about it online

Comment: I need the values of form to be available inside handlleSubmit and so a small chunk of JS is applied on onSubmit if I remove the JS and change it to  onSubmit={this.handleSignup} then there is no way the values are passed as parameters in the handleSignup method in my class.

Comment: https://redux-form.com/7.2.2/docs/faq/handlevson.md/

Comment: I guess I have done nearly the same thing here.... the onSubmit prop should take values and pass it to handleSignup but that is not working which is indeed completely unexpected.

Comment: @KOB the resource is good I have gone through it but they do nearly same thing as I did but it's not working in my case.